Manual Primality Testing methods
I am curious to know some other interesting manual methods for Primality testing. Here is one of the methods I know as of now.
Suppose let us say, we need to check whether $397$ is Prime or not.
We find $$x=\lfloor{\sqrt{397}\rfloor}=19$$
Then we list out all the primes from $2$ to $19$ and check whether any of these divides $397$. If none of them divides, we say $397$ is a Prime.
Any other ways?

Note that the questions is restricted to manual tests, i.e. amenable to hand or mental calculation. It would be a duplicate if not for that restriction (and may still be).

I would say that this is more a CS related question as it very often used in cryptography.
Primality testing is a well known problem which in 2002 has been proven to be of polynomial complexity, but to find a prime number one usually one relies on probabilistic methods as these are much faster.
Unfortunately I can't give you a good explicit reference I have used as I haven't studied the problem throughly, but to answer you question AKS and Eratosthenes Sieve are two classical algorithms that solve the problem.

For very particular numbers, there are more convenient tests, such as the Lucas-Lehmer test for testing numbers of the form $2^p - 1$ where $p$ is a prime (the so-called Mersenne numbers). It would let you check that a number like, say, $2^{13}-1 = 8191$ is prime by hand relatively quickly. (This is how all the recent "largest known prime" record holders have been found.)
The algorithm goes as follows. Start with $4$. Now, a total of $p-2$ times, repeat the below step:

Square the number you have, and then subtract $2$

If the end result is divisible by $2^p-1$, then $2^p-1$ is prime. And if not, then it isn't. The algorithm is made a lot simpler with modular arithmetic, which says that after any iteration of the bullet point above, you're allowed to subtract any multiple of $2^p-1$, and it won't change the outcome of the algorithm. That means, in the case of $p = 13$, you can make sure the number you have to square is always in the range $[-4095, 4095]$.
This might not be the most hand-calculation-friendly algorithm, but it works well with pen, paper, and a calculator capable of squaring the numbers in the given range without overflowing or losing precision. The algorithm is basically just $p-2$ steps long, as opposed to trial division, which is closer to $2^{p/2}$ steps long. So it quickly outperforms trial division, even if each step is slightly more convoluted than just checking for divisibility.
